# Como declarar uma imagem na Classe model do ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

Eu estou seguindo este tutorial da Microsoft:

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Criando um modelo de dados relacional utilizando o Entity Framework 6 mas não sei como colocar em uma classe uma variável que fosse uma imagem e serviria como foto de perfil do aluno neste caso.
Pensei em declarar algo como:

```
{
public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Id_Pessoa { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Contato")]
        public int Contato_Id { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Contato> ListaContatos { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Nome { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Sexo { get; set; }
        public string Sexualidade { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Apelido")]
        public string NickName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "RG")]
        public long Rg { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "CPF")]
        public long Cpf { get; set; }
        public float Peso { get; set; }
        public float Altura { get; set; }

       //Aqui deve haver uma foto para o perfil da pessoa
        public System.IO.MemoryStream Ft_Avatar { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basta você criar uma propriedade do tipo array de byte:

```
public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
```

Porém, dessa forma, toda vez que você carregar uma Pessoa, a imagem será carregada junto, deixando o sistema mais pesado. Por isso é recomendado criar uma classe separada para a Imagem:

```
public class ImagemPessoa
{
    [ForeignKey("Pessoa")]
    public int Pessoa_Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Imagem { get; set; }
}
```

E adicionar uma propriedade virtual na classe pessoa para acessar a imagem:

```
public virtual ImagemPessoa Avatar { get; set; }
```

Dessa forma, a imagem só será carregada se você acessar a propriedade pessoa.Avatar.

Comment: Muito obrigado.